# regex for repeating values

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the correct regex (for use with Java and JavaScript) to validate an array of day-of-week and 24-hour time formats.   I figured out the time format but am struggling to come up with the full solution.

The regex needs to validate patterns which include one or more of the following, separated by a comma.

{two-character day} HH:MM-HH:MM

Three examples of valid strings would be:

```
M 5:30-7:00
M 5:30-7:00, T 5:30-7:00, W 18:00-19:30
F 12:00-14:30, Sa 6:45-8:15, Su 6:45-8:15
```

Comment: show what u have tried

Comment: You say HH:MM, but will you allow a single digit hour?  e.g. 06 or 6

Comment: So you are saying you don't know how to make sure the string contains nothing but one or more of these formats separated by commas?

Comment: Does it mean the regex should validate something like `M 5:30-7:00, W 5:30-7:00:30` as well? (note I changed the second time deliberately).

Comment: methai: Yes, existing code which reads this string is a bit ambiguous and needs so it needs to support both single and double-digit hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should validate a 24-hour time:

```
/^((M|T|W|Th|Fr|Sa|Su) ([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](, )?)+$/
```

Credit for the time bit goes to `mkyong`: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
[A-Za-z]{1,2}[ ]\d+:\d+-\d+:\d+
```

Comment: You need to match one or two digits for the hours and two digits for minutes.

Comment: `{1,2}` I would imagine, rather than `{1:2}`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
^(M|Tu|W|Th|F|Sa|Su) \d{1,2}:\d{2}-\d{1,2}:\d{2}(, (M|Tu|W|Th|F|Sa|Su) \d{1,2}:\d{2}-\d{1,2}:\d{2})*$
```

Note that you show `T` in your example above which is ambiguous. You might want to enforce `Tu` and `Th` as shown in my regex.

Comment: @The_Land_Of_Devils_SriLanka You are correct about `^$` however `\d+` would allow one or more digits which I don't think would be desirable

Answer (score 0):

This will capture all sets in an array.  The T in the short day of week list is debatable (tuesday or thursday?).

```
^((?:[MTWFS]|Tu|Th|Sa|Su)\s(?:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})-(?:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})(?:,\s)?)+$
```

The (?:) are non-capturing groups, so your actual matches will be (for example):

- M 5:30-7:00
- T 5:30-7:00
- W 18:00-19:30

But the entire line will validate.

Added ^ and $ for line boundaries and an explicit time-time match because some regular expression parsers may not work with the previous way that I had it.

Comment: I figured the delimiter could be anything if you're just finding groups of matches - but good point!  Added, but outside of the captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: `([MTWFS][ouehra]?) ([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]):([0-6][0-9])-([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]):([0-6][0-9])`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
(((M|T(u|h)|W|F|S(a|u)) ((1*\d)|(2[0-3])):[1-5]\d-((1*\d)|(2[0-3])):[1-5]\d(, )?)+
```